# Have an unprivileged non-account user ssh into another box?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I know how to get a user to ssh into another box with a key:

```
ssh -l targetuser -i path/to/key targethost
```

But what about non-account users like `apache`?  As this user doesn't have a home directory to which it can write a `.ssh` directory, the whole thing keeps failing with:

```
$ sudo -u apache ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l targetuser -i path/to/key targethost
Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'.
Warning: Permanently added '<hostname>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've tried variations using `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` and setting `$HOME` to `/dev/null` and none of these have done the trick.  I understand that `sudo` could probably fix this for me, but I'm trying to avoid having to require a manual server config since this code will be deployed on a number of different environments.

Any ideas?

Here's a few examples of what I've tried that don't work:

```
$ sudo -u apache export HOME=path/to/apache/writable/dir/ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=path/to/apache/writable/dir/.ssh/known_hosts -l deploy -i path/to/key targethost
$ sudo -u apache ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=path/to/apache/writable/dir/.ssh/known_hosts -l deploy -i path/to/key targethost
$ sudo -u apache ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -l deploy -i path/to/key targethost
```

Eventually, I'll be using this solution to run rsync as the `apache` user.

Comment: can you add the `-vv` option to your your ssh commands and post the output?  It almost looks like the server isn't even using your key.  Are you sure apache owns the key and is the only account with write access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoredache had it.  Not a single option I passed on the command line could save me as the private key file was set to `600` permissions and owned by my own user.  My bad.  Apologies to everyone :-(

Answer (score 0):

Just create /var/www/.ssh/ and give apache write permission for it or change apache's $HOME to a directory where he can write.

Comment: The idea is to avoid having to manually configure each server to host this code.  I can do what you suggest, or configure sudo on the host, the effect is the same.  What i need is the right command(s) to have apache issue on it's own to make this request without further server configs.  Are you telling me that this isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

how about adding the following to `/etc/sudoers`

```
someuser  ALL = (apache) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync [options]
```

that will allow someuser to run `sudo -u apache /usr/bin/rsync [options]` without a password (convenient for scripting... just explicitly insert the rsync options, so they can't do anything /but/ that.)

Comment: nevermind. i missed what you had posted. of course, the updated sudoers file could be sent in batch to all your servers...

Comment: personally, i'd do it with a user, other than apache, but that's me, and i don't know the full extent of what you're dealing with...